# What's the usual term for "ground plan based"

Tags: terminology

I don't know if "ground plan based" is the right word in the following context:

A computer program reads a ground plan and produces a result ground plan. The result groundplan's deviation from the input ground plan must be within a prescribed tolerance to be called "ground plan based".

Possible words for this situation might be:

ground plan based, topographic planimetry, planimetric reconstruction

But I'm not sure which is the common word? Which word would you use to describe that both of the ground plans match nearly 100%?

Comment: I wonder if footprint is the term you are looking for?

Comment: The given example (context) is unclear, because you use the words which you want to know the definition for (or a substitute for them). Nonetheless, the result groundplan's deviation would be the 'precision' and how input compares to output the 'accuracy'.

Comment: Is the ground plan like a [plat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plat)? or [coordinate geometry / cogo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COGO)? [Metes and bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metes_and_bounds)? Surveyors often talk about how well a survey 'closes',